# How to create a web-scraper to retrieve data from a given site

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

I need to build a web scraper using BeautifulSoup to extract movie data such as url, movie name, introduction from imdb top 250 movies web page and write the extracted data into an excel file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
import lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from xlwt import *

#creating the worksheet table
workbook = Workbook(encoding = 'utf-8')
table = workbook.add_sheet('data')
table.write(0, 0, 'Number')
table.write(0, 1, 'movie_url')
table.write(0, 2, 'movie_name')
table.write(0, 3, 'movie_introduction')
line = 1

url = "https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/"
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36 QIHU 360SE'
    }
f = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
movies_lst = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(f.content,'lxml')
movies = soup.find('table', {'class': 'chart full-width'}).find_all('td', {'class': 'titleColumn'})
links = [movie.find_all('a') for movie in movies]
#print(*links)

num = 0
for anchor in links:
  urls = 'https://www.imdb.com' + anchor[0]['href']
  movies_lst.append(urls)
  num += 1
  movie_url = urls
  movie_f = requests.get(movie_url, headers = headers)
  movie_soup = BeautifulSoup(movie_f.content, 'lxml')
  movie_content = movie_soup.find('span', {'data-testid': 'plot-xl'})
  movie_name = movie_soup.find('div', {'class': 'sc-80d4314-1 fbQftq'}).find_all('h1')
  print(num, urls, '\n', 'Movie:' + movie_name[0].string.strip())
  print(movie_content.string.strip())
  print('Movie info:' + movie_content.string)

  #writing into the worksheet table
  table.write(line, 0, num)
  table.write(line, 1, urls)
  table.write(line, 2, movie_name[0].string.strip())
  table.write(line, 3, movie_content.string)
  line += 1
workbook.save('topIMDBMovies.xls')
```